# Converting 2-line gate driver PWM to 1-line 3-state

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, tri-state

I'm a software engineer, not really experienced in the hardware design, looking to confirm if I correctly designing the following piece:

I have a FOC motor controller chip (TMC4671) that is only able to provide 2-line PWM signal to the gate driver (PWM_HIGH that goes logic high to enable high side of the MOSFET half-bridge, and PWM_LOW that goes high to enable the low side. Both signals LOW means both sides of half-bridge are off, and it's not supposed to have a state where both signals are HIGH).
To simplify my schematic, I would prefer to use the "Power Stage" IC (e.g. TI CSD97395Q4M) that only has one tri-state PWM line to control it (HIGH signal means high-side on, LOW signal means low-side on, high-Z means both sides off).

I believe the following schematic (2-input NOR gate + Tri-state digital buffer with inverting ENABLE input) would work to convert signals between these 2 ICs:
[image: schematic]

Apart from making the bandwidths/timings and voltages match, is there anything I missed here? Is it supposed to work at all?

Thanks!

Comment: Just a note that if actually building this, tie any unused inputs to a power/ground rail and add decoupling capacitors at each chip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description of the problem, the OR and tri-state buffer circuit you show is fine.

It suits the PWM input pin function described in the CSD97395Q4M datasheet.